# ngAnimate max-height not working on certain element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I've implemented ngAnimate into a project to help with animations, but I'm getting really odd behaviour with a certain element.

To add some background, we have a shop with categories and products inside the categories. I'm doing an ng-repeat with: `data-ng-repeat="product in currentProductCategory.Products"` and I have `data-ng-class="{ 'open': product.ShowDetails == true }"` on my root element.

My root element also has an id of `product-{{product.Id}}-{{currentProductCategory.Id}}` and I have a child element with id `product-options-{{product.Id}}-{{currentProductCategory.Id}}` which products expected results.

When clicking a button, I call a function that sets the max-height on the parent element to a desired height, and the animation is handled in the CSS. Here's the function code:

```
var reg = /\d+/g;
var productParentElement = $('#product-' + product.Id + '-' + $scope.currentProductCategory.Id);
var optionsElement = $('#product-options-' + product.Id + '-' + $scope.currentProductCategory.Id);

var productParentPaddingTop = parseInt(productParentElement.css("padding-top").match(reg));
var productParentPaddingBottom = parseInt(productParentElement.css("padding-bottom").match(reg));
var productParentTotalHeight = productParentPaddingTop + productParentPaddingBottom + productParentElement.height() + optionsElement.height();

var optionsElementPaddingTop = parseInt(optionsElement.css("padding-top").match(reg));
var optionsElementPaddingBottom = parseInt(optionsElement.css("padding-bottom").match(reg));
var optionsElementTotalHeight = optionsElementPaddingTop + optionsElementPaddingBottom + optionsElement.height();

var totalHeight = productParentTotalHeight + optionsElementTotalHeight;

if (product.ShowDetails) {
    product.ShowDetails = true;
    productParentElement.css("max-height", totalHeight);
} else {
    product.ShowDetails = false;
    productParentElement.removeAttr('style');
}
```

And my CSS for the closed and open classes:

Closed:

```
.products-list .product {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-transition: max-height 2s ease;
    -o-transition: max-height 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 2s ease;
    transition: max-height 2s ease;
}
```

Open:

```
.products-list .product.open {
    -moz-transition: max-height 2s ease;
    -o-transition: max-height 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 2s ease;
    transition: max-height 2s ease;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

The issue is that out of the many products over 4 categories, the same one which is the same product in each category is not animating open. It animates the close/shrink, but when opening, it just instantly appears open.

This has been gating on us for a long time now and it's becoming a real issue, any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Now none of the "products" will animate open, but they do animate closed. Could this be because I'm setting the max-height on the style rather than a class?

Comment: Just for clarification - are you saying that only one of the product types within each category is not animating correctly, but all the other product types within the category are animating fine?

Comment: That's correct! Other than the values of properties on the objects being different (as they would be), the data for them all is exactly the same. There's one "product" that has the same issue across all categories. For example: JPEG (the offender) is a product in 3 categories. Each category has it's _own_ JPEG product object, they do not reference the same one. But all 3 JPEG products refuse to animate

Comment: There isn't really enough code here for me to give you a definitive answer as I'd be guessing a bit, but I would focus on what is peculiar to the problem product. Does it always appear in the same position in the list, or is there some other property that the problem product has, that the other products don't have?

Comment: The product in different categories is in different positions on the category arrays. I just updated the question because now every product instantly opens, but they do animate the close. Additionally, it's causing a delay when toggling between categories. When you click a category, there's a $scope.currentProductCategory which has an array of products. When changing to the first category, there's a delay while ngAnimate modifies the classes, but it's instant changing to a category that isn't first. I understood you'd need more code to help though!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this might sound like I am pointing out the obvious and I can't see the rest of your code but in your CSS, you have;

```
.products-list .product {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-transition: max-height 2s ease;
    -o-transition: max-height 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 2s ease;
    transition: max-height 2s ease;
}
```

for your closed list which has a 'max-height: 200px' but is also the same in your open list;

```
.products-list .product.open {
    -moz-transition: max-height 2s ease;
    -o-transition: max-height 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 2s ease;
    transition: max-height 2s ease;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Which also has a max-height of 200px. So in this case you're asking it to transition from 200px to 200px. try changing the height of open classes to be bigger or smaller. Then it will transition.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I removed the max-height from the class as I'm setting it on the element inline style through javascript. I temporarily removed ngAnimate because it was causing yet another issue and the animations work smoothly in this instance, but really we need ngAnimate because we also have a fading effect that doesn't work without it!